# npm install firebase выдает ошибку

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

```
grpc@1.16.1 install C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc
    λ npm install firebase

grpc@1.16.0 install C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.16.0 and node@10.13.0 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error socket hang up
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\Yerlan\\Desktop\\proj3\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Yerlan\\Desktop\\proj3\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Yerlan\\Desktop\\proj3\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.13.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\Yerlan\Desktop\proj3\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN slick-carousel@1.8.1 requires a peer of jquery@>=1.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vue-slick@1.1.15 requires a peer of jquery@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN vuex-router-sync@4.3.2 requires a peer of vue-router@^2.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.16.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.16.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yerlan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-19T09_32_38_550Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Так оно же ясно пишет, что не смогло найти, где у Вас установлен Python.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже мучаюсь с Firebase. В вашем случае нужно установить Python.
На Windows действенный способ, это установить windows-build-tools в который включен Python.
Подробнее описано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126050/running-python-on-windows-for-node-js-dependencies, **я процитирую важные команды**:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Затем, если по прежнему не видит его, добавляем в PATH.

```
setx PYTHON "%USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools\python27\python.exe"
```

После этого проблем с ним быть не должно. Обратите внимание на версию Пайтона, она 2.7 и это важно.
Подробнее о самом пакете здесь: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools